# How to save label text as a case property to be referenced later in a CommCare application

Tags: commcare

I'm making a CommCare application that creates action item child cases when certain questions are answered incorrectly by an end user. The end user needs to be able to reference these action item child cases in a separate module. I would like to be able to reference the question text of questions that were answered incorrectly, specifically I'd like to save that question label text as a case property in order to reference it in that later module. Is there logic or documentation available that I could reference to save the question label text as a case property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by loading the label text in a hidden variable's Calculate Condition and then reference that variable later.

#### Create a hidden variable with your label text

Add the label text to the Calculate Condition of a hidden variable question type. For example, `my_label_text`

#### Reference that variable in a question's label text box

You can drag and drop that hidden variable, `my_label_text`,  into the label portion of the question:

[image]

#### Save the hidden variable to a case property

You can then add logic to save `my_label_text` as a case property in the Case Management tab. In your scenario you may also want to add logic to save whether or not the question was answered properly.

[image]